# How to show only one modal on click in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a mini pokemon app while learning react and it is almost done but when I'm clicking I should get details about that pokemon into a modal. But instead, I get all modals with pokemons data one above each other. I am using currentTarget but is not working and can't figure out why.

My code :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useModal = (pokemon) => {
const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);
const [onePokemon, setOnePokemon] = useState([]);



const setCurrentPokemon = e => {
 setOnePokemon(e.targetTarget.name);
 console.log(setCurrentPokemon);
};


// console.log(pokemon)
function toggle() {
 setIsShowing(!isShowing);
}
return {
 setCurrentPokemon,
 onePokemon,
 isShowing,
 toggle
};
};

export default useModal;
```

My app which I'm trying to make with all my code can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-bartik-n8ity?file=/src/components/modal/useModal.js)

Can anybody can help me t figure it out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you've created 1 modal state that is shared between the multiple modals created under each pokemon within your loop, to resolve this, you can make it only one modal and then set the name and URL with either another useState within your custom hook, or in the app itself.

For example, you can change the Home.js to be like this

```
  const [modalName, setModalName] = useState("");
  const [modalUrl, setModalUrl] = useState("");
  const { isShowing, toggle, onePokemon } = useModal(pokemon);
  return (
    <Main>
      <Title>pokemons</Title>
      <PokemonDiv>
        {pokemon.map(({ name, url, id }) => (
          <PokemonWrap key={name}>
            <Figure>
              <Alink onClick={() => {
                setModalName(name);
                setModalUrl(url);
                toggle()
                } }>
                <PokeImg url={url} key={id} />
                <figcaption>
                  <Paragraph>
                    Name:
                    <Span>{name}</Span>
                  </Paragraph>
                </figcaption>
              </Alink>
            </Figure>
            
          </PokemonWrap>
        ))}
      </PokemonDiv>
      <Modal
              isShowing={isShowing}
              hide={toggle}
              onePokemon={onePokemon}
              url={modalUrl}
              name={modalName}
            />
    </Main>
```

Now you have 1 modal component and the name and URL are a state that updates it on clicking.